# Why doesn't ClickOnce in Visual Studio deploy content files from dependent assemblies?

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have a smart client application that is deployed via click once.  The problem is that i have content files in dependent assemblies that just don't show up in the published application files dialog in visual studio.

This means that everytime I deploy I have to copy all the content files from the application build output directory into the published directory and rebuild the manifests which is a real pain.

Why are these files not visible to the publisher in visual studio?

Comment: Rather annoying, and still an issue in VS 2012.

Comment: Also still an issue in VS 2013, and they broke the solutions below.

Comment: Also an issue in VS 2015.  Including them as [linked content](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11808911/3367144) in the csproj file of the dependent project works well.  Use a `<visible>false</visible>` tag if you don't want to see it in the solution explorer.

Comment: Still an issue in the newest versions...  And the linked content solution simply doesn't work for some scenarios.

Comment: Add as a Link, like @kdbanman say, change the "Copy to Output Directory" parameter to "Copy always", and change the "Build Action" parameter to "Content" work for me. Thank's

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I seemed to have found an evolution of the answer from @John Hunter that is much simpler, add this to the csproj.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Bin\**\*.rpt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This will then make visual studio automatically view all *.rpt files in that folder as part of the solution. You could go with `*.*` to accumulate everything. This makes more sense if you have a container folder like `bin\MyDeployables\**\*.*`

We followed a similar usage for using Cassette MSBuild to combine and minifiy our JS at publish time, and be able to publish the created files through the built in VS publish tooling.

Comment: Note that you will likely have to set TargetPath-s for the generated PublishFile element(s) within the project file, since otherwise they will be put within "Bin" sub-directory.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013 this will copy the files to `app.publish\Bin\Release\My Deployables\filename.ext`, when what you really want is for them to be copied to `app.publish\My Deployables\filename.ext`.

Comment: Hi all, did you manage to find a workaround for the "app.publish\My Deployables\filename.ext" issue?  Is there a way to fudge a final output folder?  If not, I'll just have to change my code to search for the files in bin\release.. messy and not ideal, but ATM with 3hrs of searching I haven't been able to get this to work.

Comment: While this may work, referencing the build output (bin) in a project seems like a very bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

I think my answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423162/deploying-content-file-from-dependent-assemblies-with-clickonce/424691#424691) answers your question.

**Summary**

Either...
Add your content files to your project using the "Add as link" feature.

Or...
Create a post-build event to copy your content files to the main output folder.

Comment: I tried all that and it doesn't work for me.  The content files from the dependent assemblies are already in the output folder but they do not show up in the application files dialog even if I select show all files.  Is there something else i am missing here?

Comment: what, specifically, are your "content files"?  what file extension do they have?

Comment: .rpt for crystal report files mostly.

Comment: Need to add a files as link and set its type to "Content".

Answer (score 3):

Ok I still don't know why Visual studio cannot display referenced content files with its publish ui but I found a work around to force the publish to include these files.

As suggested by [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mwade/how-to-publish-files-which-are-not-in-the-project), put this in the project file.

```
<ItemGroup>
<AdditionalPublishFile Include="$(OutputPath)\**\*.rpt">
  <Visible>False</Visible>
</AdditionalPublishFile>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="BeforePublish">
  <Touch Files="@(IntermediateAssembly)" />
  <CreateItem Include="@(AdditionalPublishFile)" AdditionalMetadata="TargetPath=%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(extension);IsDataFile=false">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="_DeploymentManifestFiles" />
  </CreateItem>
</Target>
```

Note that in some circumstances restarting Visual Studio (not just reloading the project) may be required for these changes to take effect.

Comment: Wish there was a way to do this using the UI.

Comment: i have tried this solution but is not workable for me, i'm use vs2013 sp1.

Comment: This no longer works on VS 2015 either.  The files get uploaded/published, but they do not get declared on any deployment manifest, so they do not get downloaded by the client.  I'm guessing `_DeploymentManifestFiles` is an internal item that isn't an officially supported output target.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this solution was based on: http://blogs.msdn.com/mwade/archive/2008/06/29/how-to-publish-files-which-are-not-in-the-project.aspx

As per my recent comment on the post:

> At what point should we expect these
>   to appear in the "Application Files"
>   listings (if at all)?
>
> Or is safe to assume they'll end up in
>   our deployed data files listing?
>
> In my case I'm hoping to use:
>
> False
>
> To include all content files from
>   dependent assemblies that are within
>   the "Resources" subfolder of the build
>   directory.

Andrew.

Comment: Thanks for this link, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the bottom of your .csproj / .vbproj fixes this issue. It takes the already cached target items of depending projects and explicitly adds them to the application manifest, which is then also published in the distribution manifest

```
<Target Name="MyAddAdditionalPublishItemsFromDependencies"    BeforeTargets="GenerateApplicationManifest">

  <!-- Get items from child projects first. This just fetches data cached by MSBuild -->
  <MSBuild
      Projects="@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)"
      Targets="GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems"
      BuildInParallel="$(BuildInParallel)"
      Properties="%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.SetConfiguration); %(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.SetPlatform); %(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.SetTargetFramework)"
      Condition="'@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != '' and '$(_GetChildProjectCopyToOutputDirectoryItems)' == 'true' and '%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.Private)' != 'false' and '$(UseCommonOutputDirectory)' != 'true'"
      ContinueOnError="$(ContinueOnError)"
      SkipNonexistentTargets="true"
      RemoveProperties="%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.GlobalPropertiesToRemove)">

    <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="_AllChildProjectItemsWithTargetPath"/>
  </MSBuild>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Filter out the interesting files from MSBuild -->
    <_AllImportedCopyItems KeepDuplicates="false" KeepMetadata="CopyToOutputDirectory;TargetPath" Include="@(_AllChildProjectItemsWithTargetPath->'%(FullPath)')" Condition="'%(_AllChildProjectItemsWithTargetPath.CopyToOutputDirectory)'=='Always' or '%(_AllChildProjectItemsWithTargetPath.CopyToOutputDirectory)'=='PreserveNewest'" />

    <!-- Get auto copied DLLs with these references -->
    <_AllReferenceAutoCopyItems KeepDuplicates="false" KeepMetadata="CopyToOutputDirectory;TargetPath" Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Release memory for huge list -->
    <_AllChildProjectItemsWithTargetPath Remove="@(_AllChildProjectItemsWithTargetPath)"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Filter non-dll -->
    <_AllReferenceAutoCopyItems Remove="%(_AllReferenceAutoCopyItems.Identity)" Condition="'%(_AllReferenceAutoCopyItems.Extension)' != '.dll'" />

    <!-- Remove items which we already have in the deployment manifest -->
    <_AllReferenceAutoCopyItems Remove="@(_DeploymentManifestFiles);@(_DeploymentManifestDependencies)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Replace items in _AllReferenceAutoCopyItems with the items emitted by the AssignTargetPath task that have the TargetPath metadata -->
  <AssignTargetPath Files="@(_AllReferenceAutoCopyItems)" RootFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)">
    <Output TaskParameter="AssignedFiles" ItemName="_Temporary" />
  </AssignTargetPath>
  <ItemGroup>
    <_AllReferenceAutoCopyItems Remove="@(_Temporary)" />
    <_AllReferenceAutoCopyItems Include="@(_Temporary)" />
    <_Temporary Remove="@(_Temporary)" />     
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- And now declare these items as files for deployment -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <_DeploymentManifestFiles Include="@(_AllImportedCopyItems)">
      <IncludeHash Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.dll' or '%(Extension)' == '.exe'">True</IncludeHash>
      <IsDataFile>false</IsDataFile>
    </_DeploymentManifestFiles>
    <_DeploymentManifestFiles Include="@(_AllReferenceAutoCopyItems)">
      <IncludeHash Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.dll' or '%(Extension)' == '.exe'">True</IncludeHash>
      <IsDataFile>false</IsDataFile>
    </_DeploymentManifestFiles>
  </ItemGroup>    
  <!-- Remove items which we will never again use - they just sit around taking up memory otherwise -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <_AllImportedCopyItems Remove="@(_AllImportedCopyItems)" />
    <_AllReferenceAutoCopyItems Remove="@(_AllReferenceAutoCopyItems)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I'm thinking about publishing this feature in a .NuGet package, to make it easier to install this script. I will post a link when I have one.