# MSBuild project file: Copy item to specific location in output directory

Tags: msbuild, csproj

In the process of cleaning up the folder/file structure on a project I inherited, I'm running into a problem with organizing the required external libraries.  I want to keep them in their own `.\dll\` folder, but they're not being copied to the build directory properly.  They should be in the root build directory, but they're being moved to a subfolder instead.

My `.csproj` file contains the following xml:

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="dlls\libraryA.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then, on build, the `libraryA.dll` file is copied to the `bin\Debug\dll\` folder, but I want it in the `bin\Debug\` folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35065306/492 - `<ContentWithTargetPath>` - probably invented long after this question

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I tried this and msbuild always wants to copy the files using their directory path, but there is a workaround...

Edit the csproj file and after this line:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

Add these lines:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PrepareForRunDependsOn>$(PrepareForRunDependsOn);MyCopyFilesToOutputDirectory</PrepareForRunDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="MyCopyFilesToOutputDirectory">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(None)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
  </Target>
```

The copy of the output files happens in the PrepareForRun target. This adds your own target to the list of targets that are executed as part of PrepareForRun.

This example copies all items in the None item group. You could create your own item group (e.g. MyFiles) and do the copy on that item group if you have other "None" files you don't want copied. When I tried this I had to change the item group name by editing the csproj file directly. Visual Studio did not allow me to set the item group of a file from the UI, but after I edited the csproj and changed it, Visual Studio displayed my custom item group name correctly.

Comment: Works like a dream, thanks!  For reference to others, I ended up creating my own group name (i.e. `<customItem include="subdir\library.dll" />`) then, I just had to make sure the CopyToOutputDirectory option was set to Never (which is the default).

Comment: Just stumbled across this solution - AWESOME!!!!! I'll also add in that you can change the `DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)"` to `DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)\%(RecursiveDir)"` if you have more than just a flat directory structure AND you can add in the extra `SkipUnchangedFiles="true"` if you only want to copy over updated files each time.. @BrianWalker - You're a freaking champ!!!!!

Comment: If it helps, for anyone else with the same kind of issue, I commented my solution using this logic here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19989390/1693085

Comment: This worked for me when i specify the files to copy. wildcards are not accepted it seems

Comment: This is nice but if I do that then it seems "dlls\libraryA.dll" ends up in "bin\dlls\libraryA.dll" and I'd like it in "bin\libraryA.dll". I can't seem to find a way to publish from a source subdir to the bin folder directly (they keep ending up in source subdir.

Answer (score 12):

If you only want to change it for one file, it may be easier to use the  property:

```
<None Include="dlls\libraryA.dll">
  <Link>%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

[Including content files in .csproj that are outside the project cone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292351/including-content-files-in-csproj-that-are-outside-the-project-cone)

Comment: As of VS 2017 version 15.6.1, this strategy causes a warning "The file 'dlls\libraryA.dll' could not be added to the project.  Cannot add a link to the file [project directory]\dlls\libraryA.dll. This file is within the project directory tree." and the file does not appear in Solution Explorer.  It does still get copied to the output root directory during the build.

Answer (score 1):

This approach works

If you need to force copy of a specific file/nuget package into an asp.net core project (2.2), add at the end of your csproj :

```
<!-- Force copy MathNet because we need it in compilation -->
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\MathNet.Numerics.4.8.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MathNet.Numerics.dll')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\MathNet.Numerics.4.8.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MathNet.Numerics.dll'))" />
</Target>

<ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="..\packages\MathNet.Numerics.4.8.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MathNet.Numerics.dll">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       <TargetPath>MathNet.Numerics.dll</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

In SDK-style csproj you can write something like:

```
  <Target Name="CopyFilesTargetName" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutDir)\dlls\Some.dll;$(OutDir)\dlls\SomeOther.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
  </Target>
```

You can also use `<Move` instead of `<Copy` to move files

Answer (score 0):

You can change the output path of an item by adding the `TargetPath` metadata to the item:

```xml
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="dlls\libraryA.dll">
      <TargetPath>%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```