# Visual Studio: How to "Copy to Output Directory" without copying the folder structure?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a few dll files in \lib folder of my project folder. In the property page of dll, I have selected "Build Action" as "Content" and "Copy to Output Directory" as "Copy always".

After build I am actually getting the dll copied but they are inside \bin\Release\lib and not in \bin\Release.

Is there a way to copy dll files to \bin\Release (and not to \bin\Release\lib) without writing a post-build script or resorting to nant etc?

Answer (score 383, accepted):

instead of `<Content>` use `<ContentWithTargetPath>` and specify target path, like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ContentWithTargetPath Include="lib\some_file.dat">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <TargetPath>some_file.dat</TargetPath>
  </ContentWithTargetPath>
  <None Include="lib\some_file.dat" />
</ItemGroup>
```

<s>Note that this entry may not be visible from Visual Studio (2012, 2015, 2017), but once manually added to the csproj, it will appear in Visual Studio. The target path will not be editable through the UI though.</s>

Adding a `<None>` entry for the file will ensure that it still shows up in Visual Studio's UI.

Comment: I don't see ContentWithTargetPath as a Build Action option in VS 2015.  Is there a way to add it?

Comment: Once I added the entry manually in the .csproj file it appears as an option in the IDE.  However I still can't edit the Target Path from the IDE.

Comment: My only worry is that this will become unsupported with future versions of MSBuild/.NET/Visual Studio/Whatever, since the VS2015 UI doesn't show this option or the TargetPath property.

Comment: It works even in Visual Studio 2012, again without any UI support.

Comment: @bitbonk I agree, it somehow works in VS2017, but in the GUI it claims `Build Action`=`None` and `Copy to Output Directory`=`Do not copy`, which is different from what I hacked into the csproj

Comment: A regular build is working, the files are going into the top-level output folder instead of a subfolder. But when I *Debug* in VS2017, all of those files disappear and I'm left only with the contents of /bin that I had before I edited .csproj  Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: @EastofNowhere.  I have VS2017 and use this technique and it still works for me when I debug my app.  I even cleaned the solution beforehand to clear out the /Debug folder and then pressed F5 and the files got moved into the root /Debug folder like I expect.

Comment: I got around this by adding a Reference to my startup project to the project with the files that were needed. Strictly by build dependencies, this should have been unnecessary. But adding this "redundant" reference did get VS to stop deleting files when running in Debug.

Comment: I have another small worry that the behaviour may be slightly confusing at first (given it's not visible in the UI) for anyone who has to make related changes in the future.

Comment: Note that using `ContentWithTargetPath` breaks incremental compilation (tested on VS 2017 15.9.9)

Comment: There is also `NoneWithTargetPath` available (see [MSBuild targets: Default build targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019#default-build-targets)).

Comment: @MadsRavn Does it fixed now? vs2019 16.8.4.

Comment: @MadsRavn, is [this](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/copytooutputdirectorypreservenewest-ignored-inside/1332219) what you mean when you said "using `ContentWithTargetPath` breaks incremental compilation"?

Comment: @TysonWilliams It has been a while since I had the issue, but yes as far as I remember using `ContentWithTargetPath ` would `CopyAlways`, which in turn would lead to always doing a full build.

Comment: How do I copy a folder with native dependencies like ..\Lib\x64\*.* to the output directory (no subfolders)?

Comment: Microsoft's engineering team has now prioritized the request to add native support for `ContentWithTargetPath` in Visual Studio 2019: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-vs-gui-support-for-contentwithtargetpath-build/1059491

Comment: ContentWithTargetPath works also fine with multiple files in this way:
`<ItemGroup>
  <ContentWithTargetPath Include="lib\**">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <TargetPath>%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
  </ContentWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>`

Comment: This also works with `dotnet build ...` or `dotnet publish ...` from console (VS2019). +1

Comment: At least with VS2019, `<TargetPath>` can be set even for build type `None`, e.g.: `<None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Directory\Foo.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>Foo.dll</TargetPath>
    </None>`

Answer (score 31):

Keep them in `$(ProjectDir)\Lib`, but add those files "[As a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)" to the root of your .csproj. Now they will get copied to bin\Debug (or whatever other output folder) without being in lib.

EDIT: This answer was written way back when ContentWithTargetPath was not available in the versions of VS/MSBuild I was using. Leaving this answer here for people who might have to use an older version of VS. Please stop commenting on this, we all know there are better ways now.

Comment: Thanks ananthonline. I tried your steps but it didn't help. May be I am doing something wrong. Here's what I'm doing, please correct if you think something is incorrect:
1. Exclude those dlls from the project but let them be in lib
2. Right click on project and "Add existing items". Select the dlls from lib and add them "as link"
3. Right click on the dlls and again select "Copy Always" in "Copy to Output Directory".
4. Clean & Rebuild.
Result: I again got those dlls in \bin\release\lib

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your solution folder after configuring it

Comment: Screen shot available here: http://imageupper.com/i/?S0200010040013Z1378913568757906

Not able to post to the question due to some strange issue with framing and security

Comment: No, you have to "Add as Link" from wherever they reside on disk, and the dll files should be directly under the project node, not under a "lib" folder node. Note that files added as a link will show a small shortcut-like arrow inside the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.

Comment: If I try to add a link to a file already in the project tree, it refuses and instead just includes the file into the project again...

Comment: Like @Nyerguds I am experiencing that you cannot add a link to a file that is already in the project tree so this answer does not solve the question.

Comment: Doesn't it flood the root of project directory in Solution Explorer? With many such files it can be a problem. Usually the root of a project directory already contains too mush various files.

Answer (score 27):

If your main intent is to include DLLs without cluttering up the project root directory, another solution is to **move the DLLs to a separate Shared Project** and add this as a reference in the original project.

(Note that this post doesn't directly answer this question as it doesn't preserve the folder and project structure, but I found this approach useful because I was able to restructure my project in my case and because I wanted to avoid some of the downsides of the other approaches here.)

Steps

- Right-click your `Solution -> Add -> New Project -> Shared Project`
- Add the DLLs to this project (in the root directory of this project, not in a "lib" sub-folder)
- (Check DLL file properties are set correctly, e.g. `Build Action: Content` and `Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always`)
- Right-click the original project's `References -> Add Reference -> Shared Projects`
- Select the shared project you created earlier

The setup looks like this:

[image: solution-explorer-screenshot]

Comment: By far the simple and elegant solution to keep the project uncluttered.

Comment: I could not get it to work with UAP and *.bin files.

Answer (score 16):

If you need to copy files from the Libs directory to the root folder VS2017:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
    <None Include="Libs\x64\**" Link="\%(Filename)%(Extension)" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
    <None Include="Libs\x86\**" Link="\%(Filename)%(Extension)" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

To any other folder, including Libs(RecursiveDir) folder

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
    <None Include="Libs\x86\**" Link="mycustomfolder\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 7):

Add the dll-files as a reference to the project, and on the reference set "Copy local" to true.

Comment: Thanks Erik. That works perfectly except for one dll that I am not able to add as a reference. The error I get while adding as reference is  A reference to 'libeay32.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Comment: @MAnthony: Only .NET assemblies or COM interop assemblies can be added as project references; native DLLs can't be. You'll need to find some other way to copy the DLL to \bin\Release.

Comment: Thanks Erik and Michael and ananthonline. Sorry can't Upvote your answers and comments as I don't have the required reputation points.

Comment: For the unmanaged DLL, you will need to use the method I suggested below.

Answer (score 7):

To add my hat into the ring here, if you want to include a whole directory of content and you don't want to track each individual file in Visual Studio, then you can add this in your project file (for me this is a `.vcxproj` file of a UWP C++ project):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Content\**">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that the `Content` directory **must be in the same directory as the project file** in order to preserve the directory structure.

Answer (score 4):

Extending [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35065306/3902603) given by [Daniel Zeitlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5852765/daniel-zeitlin):

If you'd like to copy not only a single file to the output directory, but all files in a folder, you may use the following snippet for your `.csproj` file:

```
<None Update="my-directory/*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <TargetPath>%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
</None>
```

This copies all files from `$(ProjectDir)/my-directory` directly to the `$(OutputDir)` *(**NOT** `$(OutputDir)/my-directory`)* upon compiling (assuming that the respective files are newer than the ones in the `$(OutputDir)`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems in VisualStudio 2015 that if the dlls you are 'adding with a link' are *in a subfolder of that same project* - they will be automatically put a folder, and the output is also placed in a folder like you saw.

If the dlls are in another project or directory on disk *not in a subfolder of the project*, you can 'Add with a link', and they will be put in the root directory just fine.

Comment: Same in VS2012. It refuses to make them a link, and just adds them as content. In the end, sadly the easiest solution seems to be to dump them in the project root.

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions did not work reliably for me in `Visual Studio 2019 Professional v16.8.2`. Sometimes the files would copy, sometimes not. After many attempts, it feels like something may have been broken in the latest updates to VS.

This answer shows how to use a post-build script...something the OP asks **not** to do! So this answer is intended only for those (who like me) were unable to get more traditional methods to work.

- Right-click the project and select Add > Existing Item...
- Navigate to the `lib` folder and select the item(s) to add
- To the right of `Add`, click the down arrow and choose `Add As Link`
- Right-click each file in the new "lib" folder in your project, and set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Do not copy"
- Open project properties `Build Events` and add the following Post-build event

,

```
rem Copy 3rd party DLL(s) to the output directory on successful build
COPY $(ProjectDir)lib\Something.dll $(TargetDir)
COPY $(ProjectDir)lib\SomethingElse.dll $(TargetDir)
```

Note that you can use wildcards in the post-build event to copy multiple files.

Comment: This is the most common approach I've seen on projects I worked on.
Also, you can use xcopy with /d /y flags so it will only copy the files if they are newer.
There are a few more options for xcopy that might be useful for build events.

Comment: Using copy or xcopy is arcane way. We are cleaning up all our projects lately from using copy commands in post build event blocks. They tend to mess up the incremental builds. This can be accomplished via builtin methods like the one suggested above.

Comment: @videoguy: Not arcane, but simple and works well. If you have more complicated requirements, use something else.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question, the following steps worked for me in **Visual Studio 2019**:

In the Visual Studio editor, for your dll, set the "Build Action" setting as "Content" (This might be optional) and **"Copy to Output Directory"** setting as **"Do not copy"**.

The following will then be generated within the project **csproj** file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="lib\IncludedDLL.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Modify the entry to the following instead:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="lib\IncludedDLL.dll" />
  <Content Include="lib\IncludedDLL.dll">
    <Link>IncludedDLL.dll</Link>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

You can set **"CopyToOutputDirectory"** option within the project **csproj** file **manually** to either **"Always"** or **"PreserveNewest"**.

In the Visual Studio editor, **it will still show the file "Copy to Output Directory" setting as "Do not copy"**, but the file **will be copied** to the root output directory **upon rebuild**.

The above change is not needed if you do not want to copy the file to the root output directory, so if that is the case, you can just manually remove the above change within the project csproj file to revert to the non copying behavior.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method is just to leave the items as type `None`. In the solution explorer, click on the ones you want to deploy and set the `Content` property to `True`.

*Note: I did this in VS2019, and things can change from version to version.*

To get this to work, now right-click on your project, and select "Unload Project". Then right-click on the unloaded project and select "Edit project_name.vcxproj".

In the editor, go all the way to the bottom of the file and insert this target right right before the trailing `</Project>` tag:

```
  <Target Name="CopyContent" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(None)" Condition="'%(None.DeploymentContent)' == 'true'" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" ContinueOnError="true" />
  </Target>
```

Now right click on the unloaded project and select "Reload Project". Select to save and close if you are prompted.

I also set the `OutputDirectory` to:

`$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\`

and the `IntermediateDirectory` to:

`$(SolutionDir)obj\$(Configuration)\$(ProjectName)\$(Platform)\`

in the Project Properties General page. This puts the output in a "bin" folder, and the intermediates in an "obj" folder in the root of your solution.

*Note: The `$(SolutionDir)` is not defined when you run MSBuild from the command line. There is a trick you can use to define that to the folder where the .sln file lives using GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove. (left as an exercise for the reader). Also, it looks like in 2019 they are handling this correctly on the command line anyway. Yeah :)* The `$(SolutionDir)` contains a trailing backslash, hence none after it. The results of each must have a trailing backslash.

Now, if you own Pro or above, please don't do this every time you need to create a project. That would be lame. Instead, once you have your project setup just the way you like it, select `Project -> Export Template`. You give it a name, and the next time you want to create a project just like that one, just choose that name in the New Project dialog. (In older version, I think this was `Files -> Export Teamplate...`.)

Answer (score 0):

After searching through countless older posts, I came across this:

The snippet below lets me copy the files using a glob pattern but flatten them into the output folder. I hope this helps.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="MyDirectory/**" Link="%(LinkBase)\%(Filename)%(Extension)" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

> If setting the Link metadata automatically, the value will be set to
> %(LinkBase)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension). If LinkBase or
> RecursiveDir are not defined, then those pieces will be left out of
> the value. So  would show the items under the "Shared" folder in solution
> explorer, instead of the root, and would preserve any heirarchy under
> the shared folder.

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2795#issuecomment-350538317

Answer (score 0):

ContentWithTargetPath does not seem to be necessary (any longer) to copy the file to a different location. I have updated the code from the accepted awnser to what I would be using.
Additionally, the *Content* build action serves a different purpose, as can be read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022). For including DLLs, I recommend the build action *None*.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="lib\some_file.dat" >
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <TargetPath>%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2010 / C# Project.

For assemblies (i. e. having the .NET interface) use folder "References" under your project in the Solution Explorer. Right click it, choose "Add existing item" and locate your .dll assembly.

Common .dll files can be placed in a subfolder (as "\lib" was mentioned above) and in the properties select:

- Build Action = "HelpFiles"
- Copy To OutputDirectory = "If Newer"

This worked for me exactly as desired - during build, the .DLLs are copied to the output directory without the "\lib" subfolder.