# Publish Project to Web Server, Include folders/files in Local Bin

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I have a Visual Studio 2013 Web Project with Umbraco and UCommerce imported into the project and a site built out.

The issue is that uCommerce adds a folder called uCommerce in the build directory with all of it's dependency dll's and Publish doesn't include it in the destination.

Is there a way I can set the project file to include all contents in the Bin folder for the publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the uCommerce-stuff as Content in your project. To do this, either

- Go through each and every file in the uCommerce folder and add it to your project using "Add -> Existing item...", or, if that's way too many files,
- Include the uCommerce folder via a wildcard. You will need to edit your project file manually for this. [This SO question has the details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292351/including-content-files-in-csproj-that-are-outside-the-project-cone) (make sure to check out the highest-ranked answer, not just the accepted answer).