# Having trouble deploying reactjs and .net 4.8 backend to iis

Tags: .net, reactjs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

So I have tried deploying an application using .net 4.8 backend and reactjs as frontend. I followed this [guide](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2018/03/08/create-a-build-pipeline-for-angular-and-asp.net-core-apps-with-visual-studio-team-services/).

I built both agent steps, both artifacts in release but when its deploy the contents of the 'dist' artifacts does not go in to '/ClientApp/dist' its just dumped in the rootfolder. Also, there is no 'dist' folder in the repo, I want this to be created, and that is also supposed to happen according to this tutorial. I run webpack and the output is './ClientApp/dist/'.

I've tried putting the frontend build step Target folder to:  buildvariables + /(projectname)/ClientApp/dist', just '/ClientApp/dist', just '/ClientApp/' but it either dumps it in the root folder or I get a build error like this:

> Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: d:\a\1\a\ClientApp\dist\

Here are some images of the steps:

Build:

[image]
[image]

Release:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How do I build this, and deploy it so that the 'dist' artifact ends up in '/ClientApp/dist' and the folder 'dist' is created for it?

Comment: Normally,npm run build react app generates the `build` folder by default. How do you combine `webpack` with `react` app and define the output path is `./ClientApp/dist/`

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT so, the "npm run build" step has the command "run build" which is specified in the package.json and references the the webpack. Like this: "prod": "set NODE_ENV=production&& webpack --mode=production", and in the webpack the output is specified like this: path: "path.resolve(__dirname, "./ClientApp/dist/"),"

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT All of this works perfectly fine locally. The dist folder is created and has the all the bundled scripts and so on.. This also works if I specify Target folder: "(Projectname)/ClientApp/". Then the dist folder is created on the server, but it is created in the (Projectname) root. If I specify Target folder: "(projectname)/ClientApp/dist" everything in the dist folder just gets dumped in the (projectname) root. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I tested with a simple sample, specify output in webpack.config.js as `./ClientApp/dist/`.

Run `npm run build` on the local visual studio , `clientApp / dist` folder will be automatically created in the root. But if you use hosted agent to run in azure devops, the created folder will not be displayed in the repo, because the project has been checked out to the agent, this is normal.

[image]

[image]

> Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found
>   PathtoPublish: d:\a\1\a\ClientApp\dist\

This error is due to the incorrect specification of your publish path,you need to specify the correct publish path. In my case,it works well:

[image]