# Publishing a Web Application from VS2012 is wiping out user content

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msdeploy

I'm attempting to use Web Deploy to Publish a Web Application. 
I want Visual Studio to delete any files that no longer exist, so I've checked the "Remove additional files at destination" setting in my Publishing profile.
However, I want VS to ignore the /Content/uploads folder, as it contains contents that my users have uploaded. Naturally, the contents are different in my development site than they are in the live site.
Unfortunately, I have been unable to discover a way to make Visual Studio ignore this folder when publishing (it wants to delete all of the content, since it doesn't exist in the project).
Does anyone know of a way to exclude specific folders on the target site from being examined by Web Deploy?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. My title was "VS 2012 Web Deploy wiping out user content." I wanted to specify VS 2012 Web Deploy as opposed to some random "Web Deploy". 
How is this different from posts like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137880/how-to-get-visual-studio-publish-functionality-to-include-files-from-post-buil?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the phrasing of my title?
Would "How do I prevent Visual Studio 2012's Web Deploy from wiping out user content?" be a better title?

Comment: FYI, "Web Deploy" is not part of VS2012, really. It's mostly a separate component from the IIS people. I'll edit your title to make the distinction clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a suitable solution for this issue, so I've created my own:
https://pubsync.codeplex.com/

PubSync enables quick and reliable file syncing for publishing Visual Studio projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, wanting to keep some files in the deployment package even though they're not part of the project.

Try to create a custom MSBuild target for this, that works for me.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/25/the-visual-studio-blog.aspx) is a Getting Started MSBuild reference

Hope this helps.
All the best.

Comment: Here is another add that can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137880/how-to-get-visual-studio-publish-functionality-to-include-files-from-post-buil

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've actually already been to both of those links in my search, and they don't seem to have what I'm looking for. They deal with including / excluding content from the deployment package.
I'm looking for a way to exclude content that exists on the target server.