# Post build events file to be include During publish

Tags: c#

On publish i want to include file created using post build events.
In my Ms build i can see it is included in

```
 <PropertyGroup>
      <PostBuildEvent>copy  "$(SolutionDir)\..\References\PP.txt" "$(ProjectDir)"                               </PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But it is not included when i publish,
 Any one can help me on this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Visual Studio 'Publish' functionality to include files from post build event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137880/how-to-get-visual-studio-publish-functionality-to-include-files-from-post-buil)

Comment: what do u mean to say exactly?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question seems to be already asked by someone else. Check the related link.

Comment: I checked but i am not able to relate in my .cproj <propertyGroup> i can see the file included and in target attribute i have mention <Target Name="BeforePublish">
    <Exec Condition="'$(PostBuildEvent)' != ''"
          WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PostBuildEvent)" />
  </Target>