# Exclude folder when building from VSO to Azure website

Tags: msbuild, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I am trying to exclude certain files/folders from deployment of a web project in Visual Studio Online to an Azure website.
The web project has a `Content` folder with CSS, JS, build scripts and so on, which are only necessary for development, once deployed to Azure the CSS and JS is loaded from a CDN. Currently the build from VSO is copying all those files to the webroot in Azure, which is unnecessary and a potential security issue in case of the build scripts.

Now I know this can be prevented by setting the build action of a file to `None`, but this a very tedious solution because there is a lot of development going on, new files get added all the time and it is easy to forget this setting.

First I tried setting the `Content` folder to `Cloaked` in the build definitions source settings, but this only causes VSO to not download this folder on build, msbuild will still complain that those files are missing.

Is there a way to tell msbuild to ignore the whole `Content` folder? I already tried adding `/p:ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment="Content"` as a msbuild argument in the build definition, and also tried the solutions in here [How to get Visual Studio 'Publish' functionality to include files from post build event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137880/how-to-get-visual-studio-publish-functionality-to-include-files-from-post-buil), but nothing is working.

Comment: Why not deploy it anyways?

Comment: Have you considered continuing to deploy these assets and setting up a fallback system just in case your CDN Endpoints are unavailalbe.. Read this article http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx to understand what I am referring to.

Comment: @LukkhaCoder Well as I said it is a potential security issue having some of those files on the web server. Also copying all this unnecessary stuff is causing the builds to take longer, which costs us VSO build minutes in the end.

Comment: @cory-fowler Thanks, yes we already have a 2nd CDN as a fallback. For production we also bundle and minify all of our CSS and JS, so we don't want the original files up there with all the development comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was studying *msbuild* log files and came up with a solution that is good enough for us to work with.

The first thing I learned was that I cannot prevent *msbuild* from copying files with build action `Content` to the output directory, at least not without changing the *Microsoft.WebApplication.targets* file, which I didn't want to do and am not even sure is possible with VSO build.

Anyway because of this we cannot set the source settings of our `Content` folder to `Cloaked` in the build definition, since this will cause the build to fail.

What we ended up doing was described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3140349/1230302
So by adding the `ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment` statement to the *.csproj* file, the `Content` folder is excluded from the webroot.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>Content</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It is not an ideal solution, but at least this way nothing gets deployed if a developer forgets to set the build action to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

The built in continuous delivery options are designed for convenience. Of you need something custom, like skipping deployment of files that have not changed, then you will need to write something yourself.

You can easily call PowerShell to complete any task from the build process.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to customize your build as part of the VSO build system, you can just override your BuildTemplate.xaml file.

Visual Studio Build uses Windows Workflow (xaml) to make a workflow on what the build is supposed to do. You can edit this file and do any modifications to the directory structure before or after the build.

Here is an [example](http://www.software-architects.com/devblog/2014/02/21/Customizing-Build-Workflows-in-Visual-Studio-Online).

Comment: That's intersting, thanks. I did not know about that. Anyway as it turned out my problem was msbuild and not VSO.