# How to not deploy 'App_Code' with website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops

When I build and deploy a website with `Azure DevOps`, it automatically deploys the `App_Code` folder. I would like this folder not to be deployed, as the website will not load (the website is precompiled).

Currently, each time the website is deployed, I need to manually delete the `App_Code` folder.

I am assuming it is to do with the `MSBuild Arguments`, but if I am wrong, let me know. Here are the current arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
/p:WebPublishMethod=Package
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

It would be nice to either have the `App_Code` folder not deployed, or the website not precompiled.

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004423/exclude-folder-when-building-from-vso-to-azure-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following parameter to the `MSBuild Arguments`:

```
/p:ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment="App_Code"
```

The `App_Code` is now no longer deployed.