# Azure WebJobs in .NET Core Using VS 2017 15.3

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Just installed the preview version of Visual Studio 2017 15.3 but I still don't see a way to create WebJobs in .NET Core. Is this available -- even as a preview or beta -- or not?

PS: This is NOT a duplicate question as suggested by moderators. I'm simply stating that the suggestion made in the other post did NOT work.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure WebJob in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268344/azure-webjob-in-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

With .NET Core Framework the way to create a WebJob it's a bit different. You need to use 
**Console Application(.NET Core)**.

[image]

I highly recommend you to follow this guide [**Azure WebJobs In .NET Core**](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/10/09/azure-webjobs-in-net-core-part-1/)

---

---

**This is my working example of simple WebJob :**(Using Core 2.2)

(*Program*)

```
public class Program
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot config { get; private set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        Console.WriteLine($"Current Environment : {(string.IsNullOrEmpty(environment) ? "Development" : environment)}");

        config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

        Console.WriteLine("URL API:" + config["appsettings node"]);


        var builder = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebJobs(webJobConfiguration =>
            {
                webJobConfiguration.AddTimers();
                webJobConfiguration.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            })
            .ConfigureServices(serviceCollection => serviceCollection.AddSingleton<TimeneyeTasks>())
            .Build();

        builder.Run();
    }
}
```

(*My class:*)
[image]

I hope it helps!!

Comment: please do not post screenshots of code, post the code!