# Dot net core webjob -> ServiceBus consumer

Tags: .net-core, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have created a very simple `publisher` and `subscriber` solution using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions) tutorial. I want to host the subscriber into azure as continuously executing `webjob` which consumes all the event sent out to particular topic.

Subscriber is a simple dotnet core application which runs fine on local development machine.

I have wrapped all the content of 'Debug' ( or 'Release') folder into zip file which contains a `batfile` name `taskRunner.bat` as an entrypoint for webjob to begin execution. Below are content of the `taskRunner.bat`

```
dotnet SBClient.dll
```

`SBClient.dll` is an assembly which contains logic to fetch messages out of topic.
When I run this batchfile on my machine things are are fine.  But the moment I deploy this as a webjob in my azure webjobs I get to see below errors and status of WebJob remains `PendingRestart`

```
[01/11/2018 03:51:51 > f07a91: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\coretask\kigmen2q.zmj>dotnet SBClient.dll 
[01/11/2018 03:51:51 > f07a91: ERR ] Error:
[01/11/2018 03:51:51 > f07a91: ERR ]   An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (SBClient.deps.json) was not found:
[01/11/2018 03:51:51 > f07a91: ERR ]     package: 'Microsoft.Azure.Amqp', version: '2.1.2'
[01/11/2018 03:51:51 > f07a91: ERR ]     path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.dll'
[01/11/2018 03:51:51 > f07a91: ERR ] 
[01/11/2018 03:51:51 > f07a91: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -2147450740
[01/11/2018 03:51:51 > f07a91: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
[01/11/2018 03:51:51 > f07a91: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
```

Looking at the message I can tell that its looking for a file named 'Microsoft.Azure.Amqp' but don't know how its working on my machine.

Dose that mean I don't have latest version of dotnet core on Azure?
Is there any setting that I need to configure to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, you're missing `Microsoft.Azurem.Amqp.dll` assembly which is a dependency for `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` assembly. Does your zip file contains all the required dependency assemblies including AMQP assembly?

Comment: you are right,  my zip file don't have this file but on my local machine since dotnet core framework is installed it is picking from GAC ( I guess ) .  And that's what my question is.  don't we have dot net core framework install on the virtual machine where we deploy our webjobs? I check webapp->Application Setting and it says version of webapp is v4.7   I can't change it to .net core 2 ( on azure portal )

Comment: WebJobs are hosted under Azure App Service which has support for a full .NET framework. You should be able to run your WebJob using full framework w/o a problem (the ASB client can run under both). As for how to run a webjob with .NET Core, there are quite a few resources, including [similar questions on StackOverlfow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268344/azure-webjob-in-net-core) and [blog posts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/07/how-to-deploy-a-net-core-console-application-to-azure-webjob/).