# Clickonce executable reference problem

Tags: .net, dependencies, clickonce

I have a .Net 2.0 solution with several projects.

The solution contains *MainProject* which has, as a reference, *HelperProject* (C# Console Application).

*MainProject* occasionally uses the .exe created by *HelperProject*.

The problem that I'm having is that *HelperProject* contains a *Content.xml* file. The build-action is set to "Content" and Copy to Output Directory is set to "Always".

When I compile the application all the files show up in the debug directory, but when I go to publish *MainProject*, the content file for *HelperProject* doesn't make it to the end user.

**Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?**

And

**What should I do to make content from HelperProject appear in the published version of MainProject?**

Thanks,

-Z

Comment: I haven't digested all the details, but [this question has been asked before on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590227/why-doesnt-clickonce-in-visual-studio-deploy-content-files-from-dependent-assemb).  I did a *very* quick test with the suggestion to modify the .csproj file (substituting Content.xml for the *.rpt wildcard they were after in that other thread).  It didn't work for me.  But adding Content.xml as a link to MainProject, and setting it as Content/Copy Always did work -- then Content.xml would be included in publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the xml file is set to publish with the application, be sure to check the Application Files dialog and make sure it is set to Include and not to Include(Data).

By default, ClickOnce considers XML files to be data, and deploys them to the \data\ folder under the ClickOnce cache instead of putting them in the same folder as the application.