# File cannot be found when relative path is used

Tags: wpf, componentone

In my WPF caliburn.micro application, I use ComponentOne's C1DocumentViewer to display a report.

I created in the project a new Folder “Reports” and placed the .xml there. I show the report using `C1DocumentViewer`. When provide the absolute path to the .xml file, it works fine. But of course I need to use a relative path. So if I make it “`../../MyProject/Reports/MyReport.xml`”, it works on my machine when I run it in Visual Studio. But not when I publish it using ClickOnce, it just cannot find the file. Same thing if I use “`/Reports/MyReport.xml`” or “`Reports/MyReport.xml`”.
When I try to use “`Reports/MyReport.xml`” when I debug in Visual Studio, it is looking for the path “`Reports/MyReport.xml`” in bin/Debug of the main project of the solution.

Please help. Here is my code:

```
        protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        base.OnViewLoaded(view);

        var rpt = new C1.C1Report.C1Report();

        rpt.Load(@"Reports/MyReport.xml", "Recent Files Information");

        rpt.DataSource.RecordSource = "MyReportProc(1)";
        rpt.Render();
        Report = rpt.FixedDocumentSequence;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess. Your problem might be related to the [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of your process.

> When the process refers to a file using a simple file name or relative
>   path (as opposed to a file designated by a full path from a root
>   directory), the reference is interpreted relative to the current
>   working directory of the process.

Check it with [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) when you run your program in Visual Studio and also when you run it after publishing it with ClickOnce.

Comment: @DavidShochet Have you checked that '../../MyProject/Reports/MyReport.xml' is a correct relative path from the working directory returned by GetCurrentDirectory() when the program is run after installed by ClickOnce?

Comment: I don't see the .xml file there at all. Looks like ClickOnce just doesn't copy it to the destination.

Comment: I use it like this:  rpt.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Reports\RecentFilesInformation.xml", "Recent Files Information");  This way, the Reports folder with the .xml file is copied into bin/Debug of the main project when the solution is rebuilt, and then it works when run from Visual Studio. But when I publish it, the .xml is not found, it doesn't exist in the destination folder. I guess there may be something about the .xml file attributes that prevents it from being copied to the destination path by ClickOnce.

Comment: @DavidShochet Maybe the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605936/clickonce-file-missing can help you as well.

Comment: Thanks Bill, yes, this works when I place the report into the main project. But is it possible to add it as a link so that the project stayed not in the main project?

Comment: @DavidShochet I'm afraid I do not understand your question.