# Why doesn't ClickOnce in Visual Studio deploy content files from dependent assemblies?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

*Note: this question is pretty much just a copy+paste of [Why doesn't ClickOnce in Visual Studio deploy content files from dependent assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590227/160173). However, the author of that question accepted his own answer, which did not actually answer the question that was asked in the least bit.*

---

If you have content files in dependent assemblies, the files just don't show up in the Publish->Application Files dialog in Visual Studio.

This has been a problem with Click Once since at least Visual Studio 2008, and is still not addressed in Visual Studio 2013.

The current behavior is asinine; an application that doesn't need it's dependencies' dependencies doesn't make any sense.

**Can someone from Microsoft answer *why* these dependency files are not ClickOnce publishable?** Is there some other prefered method of publishing these dependencies?

Comment: there is another answer on that question from Chris Marisic. doesn't that work for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't ClickOnce in Visual Studio deploy content files from dependent assemblies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590227/why-doesnt-clickonce-in-visual-studio-deploy-content-files-from-dependent-assem)

Comment: The question is *why* is it like this? Which none of those answers address. And no, none of those answers actually work in Visual Studio 2013.