# Cannot add content file into ClickOnce Application Files

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have a NLog .config file Build Action is set as Content in my .NET application as seen in the picture. When I wanted to publish the project as ClickOnce application I do not see it in Application Files dialog. So, after the publish it is missing.

I tried the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423162/deploying-content-file-from-dependent-assemblies-with-clickonce) question but it did not worked. What is wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Zolbayar yes, I found a solution that worked for me. Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .config file was belonged to a DLL project in my solution. Even such files are copied to the output bin folder if they are set as 'Content', they do not appear when the application is deployed as click once.

I think ClickOnce only takes required files of the Application project into consideration. I have added the .config file [Add as a Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082(v=vs.105).aspx) into Application's folder and set it as 'Content'. This worked for me. Now I see the file in ClickOnce deployment folder.